# Bundling failed pass.get() is not a function

Tags: react-native

I am struggling with this problem, can someone help me please and thanks. When i try to build and run my app i get this error : **pass.get(...) is not a function**

[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3URY.png)

[error in console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpjAu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.